# facing some difficulty in json parsing

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 My json response is below

    {  
       "groups":[  
          {  
             "storeId":"440f0991-9ac5-41b9-9e84-d3b2a2d27c13",
             "name":"oty",
             "description":"ga",
             "image":null,
             "bookCount":2,
             "members":[  
                {  
                   "bookId":"9b765d0f-3d6f-4fc1-a4a7-af807c39a004",
                   "bookName":"Anantha"
                },
                {  
                   "bookId":"f8616ab1-eeb3-403b-8182-b42e39f4b948",
                   "bookName":"lok"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }

My code for parsing json

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("groups");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                 String storeid = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("storeId");
                String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                String description =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                String bookCount = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("bookCount");
              JSONArray memberJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("members");
                for (int j = 0; j < memberJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                    String bookId = memberJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("bookId");
                    String bookName = memberJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("bookName")
                    GroupsDto groupDtoData = new GroupsDto();
                    groupDtoData.setGroupName(name);
                    groupDtoData.setGroupServerId(storeId);


                    groupDtoData.setbookname(bookName);
                    groupDtoData.setbookid(bookId);

                   groupDto.add(groupDtoData);
                    db.addGroups(groupDtoData);
                }
            }
but I got result as if book name is twice then the storeId is also twice.simillarly increse in no of book name,store id also increse.so it reflect on the list view having duplicate store name.
I/System.out: storeId 440f0991-9ac5-41b9-9e84-d3b2a2d27c13
I/System.out: bookName Ananta
I/System.out: storeId groupid440f0991-9ac5-41b9-9e84-d3b2a2d27c13
 I/System.out: bookname Lok
```

But i want with one storeId there are two book name but store id also getting twice 
please give some idea how to parse this type of json.I have facing this problem for json parsing But i want with one storeId there are two book name but store id also getting twice

Comment: I would consider using Gson for Serialization & de-serialization. It's much cleaner, easier and can catch errors easily.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize and De-serialize using Gson.
1. Create a model Class, for your case would look like below.

```
public class MyResponse {

@SerializedName("groups")
private List<Groups> groupsList;

public List<Groups> getGroupsList() {
    return groupsList;
}

public class Groups {

    @SerializedName("storeId")
    private String storeId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("bookCount")
    private String bookCount;

    @SerializedName("members")
    private List<Members> members;

    public String getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getBookCount() {
        return bookCount;
    }

    public List<Members> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public class Members {

        @SerializedName("bookId")
        private String bookId;

        @SerializedName("bookName")
        private String bookName;

        public String getBookName() {
            return bookName;
        }

        public String getBookId() {
            return bookId;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Make sure you add Gson Lib on your gradle file if using android studio

   dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
   }
3. Use the response String, for your case is the message object and convert it to a response object like below.

   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

   MyResponse myResponse = gson.fromJson(message, MyResponse.class);